# Mock class instances without calling `__init__` and mock their respective attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a class `MyClass` with a complex `__init__` function.

This class had a method `my_method(self)` which I would like to test.

`my_method` only needs attribute `my_attribute` from the class instance.

**Is there a way I can mock class instances without calling `__init__` and by setting the attributes of each class instance instead?**

What I have:

```py
# my_class.py

from utils import do_something

class MyClass(object):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # complicated function which I would like to bypass when initiating a mocked instance class
       pass

   def my_method(self):
      return do_something(self.my_attribute)
```

What I tried

```py
@mock.patch("my_class.MyClass")
def test_my_method(class_mock, attribute):
   
   instance = class_mock.return_value
   instance.my_attribute = attribute

   example_instance = my_class.MyClass()

   out_my_method = example_instance.my_method()
   # then perform some assertions on `out_my_method`
```

however this still makes usage of `__init__` which I hope we can by-pass or mock.

Comment: I'd say put your complicated stuff into an other function that is called in `__init__` and you can simply mock it away.

Comment: One simple way is `MyClass.my_method(any_object_with_my_attribute)` (i.e. call the method on the class and supply your own "instance"), but the problem you're having suggests the issue is in the design of MyClass and any quick fix is just a workaround that doesn't solve the problem. Can you give more context?

Comment: @KlausD. The idea is valid but ideally, I would avoid changing the structure of the main code

Comment: @jonrsharpe The init function loads files from disk among other things that I am taking charge of in another unit test. In this case, I would like to test each class method without having to instantiate a class instance. The answer provides a clean and readable way of implementing your suggestion.

Comment: *"I would like to test each class method without having to instantiate a class instance"* - again, that suggests poor design. For example, you could split out the loading of files into a classmethod, so the actual `__init__` just takes the *data* - `MyClass.from_file("path/to/file")`.

Comment: I have that loading method separate from `__init__` and called by `__init__`. What I understand is that I should mock that loading method. This makes sense actually.

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend that either; mocking out parts of the thing you're trying to test is an antipattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, one way to test a single method without having to create an instance is:

```
MyClass.my_method(any_object_with_my_attribute)
```

The problem with this, as with both options in [quamrana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62550066/3001761), is that we have now expanded the scope of any future change *just because of the tests*. If a change to `my_method` requires access to an additional attribute, we now have to change both the implementation **and** something else (the `SuperClass`, the `MockMyClass`, or in this case `any_object_with_my_attribute_and_another_one`).

---

Let's have a more concrete example:

```
import json


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        self.foo = data.foo
        self.bar = data.bar
        self.baz = data.baz

    def my_method(self):
        return self.foo ** 2
```

Here any test that requires an instance of `MyClass`. is painful because of the file access in `__init__`. A more testable implementation would split apart the detail of how the data is accessed and the initialisation of a valid instance:

```
class MyClass:
    
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def my_method(self):
        return self.foo ** 2

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        return cls(data.foo, data.bar, data.baz)
```

You have to refactor `MyClass("path/to/file")` to `MyClass.from_json("path/to/file")`, but wherever you already *have* the data (e.g. in your tests) you can use e.g. `MyClass(1, 2, 3)` to create the instance without requiring a file (you only need to consider the file in the tests of `from_json` itself). This makes it clearer what the instance actually *needs*, and allows the introduction of other ways to construct an instance without changing the interface.

Comment: many thanks for writing it out and spending time on this. Although it is not the answer to the question, it is a great explanation of why the question should not arise.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options I can see:

1. Extract a super class:

   ```
   class SuperClass:
       def __init__(self, attribute):
           self.my_attribute = attribute
      def my_method(self):
         return do_something(self.my_attribute)

   class MyClass(SuperClass):

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(attribute)   # I don't know where attribute comes from
          # complicated function which I would like to bypass when initiating a mocked instance class
   ```

   Your tests can instantiate `SuperClass` and call `my_method()`.
2. Inherit from `MyClass` as is and make your own simple `__init__()`:

   ```
   class MockMyClass(MyClass):
       def __init__(self, attribute):
           self.my_attribute = attribute
   ```

   Now your test code can instantiate `MockMyClass` with the required attribute and call `my_method()`

   For instance, you could write the test as follows

   ```
   def test_my_method(attribute):

      class MockMyClass(MyClass):
         def __init__(self, attribute):
            self.my_attribute = attribute

      out_my_method = MockMyClass(attribute).my_method()
      # perform assertions on out_my_method
   ```

Comment: I was expecting the `Mock` class to be used but not at all. I like the second option. It is clean and readable. I tested it on my use case and it works

Comment: The problem with both of these methods is in the scope of future changes. If `my_method` starts to need other attributes, for example, there are now more places to edit *just because of the tests*.