# Unit test for classes with complex __init__

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a class that has several methods and I would like to write unit tests for them. The problem I'm facing is that this class has an `__init__` method that queries a database, imagine something like this:

```py
class MyClass:

    accepted_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
    def __init__(self, database_name):
        self.database = database_name
        self.data = self.query_database()

    def query_database(self):
        data = query_this_database(self.database)
        # clean data
        return data

    def check_values_in_db(self, column_name):
        column = data.column_name
        
        if any(item not in self.accepted_values for item in column):
            print('Oh noes!')
        else:
            print('All good')
```

Now, given this, I would like to unit test the last method using some mock data, but I can't because if I initialize the class, it will want to query the database. This is further complicated by the fact that to actually make the query, one needs an API key, permissions, etc., which is exactly what I want to avoid during unit testing.

I'm relatively new to OOP and unit testing in general, so I'm not even sure if I structured my class properly: maybe the method `query_database()` should only be called at a later stage and not in `__init__`?

**EDIT:**

Asked to add some details so here goes:

This class belongs to an AWS lambda function that runs on a schedule. Every hour, this class queries the DB for the last hour, and checks a specific column against some pre-defined values.

If any value in the column does not belong to those pre-defined values, it sends an alert email. I would like to test this specific functionality, but without having to query the database, but just using mock values.

I edited the code accordingly to reflect what I mean.

Comment: Can you provide more context? For example, if your class only uses the database during initialisation, maybe make that an *alternate constructor* as a `@classmethod`? If it have responsibilities other than accessing the database, then maybe it should be split into two classes? And so on.

Comment: added more details as you asked

Comment: Should that be a class at all? It seems to pretty much just have one method and `__init__`, which is when you [stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). It seems like the only think you need to do is mock out `query_this_database`, though, which should be straightforward.

Comment: The class is much larger than this, I wrote a very simplified version of it for the purpose of the question, but I'll definitely check out the video you suggested.
PS: can you elaborate on what u mean with "mock out"? Are you referring to this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63157215/12127578

Comment: The `unittest.mock` part, yes; I wouldn't recommend writing a fake `__init__` to get around your current design. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551946/3001761.

Comment: Ok cool! Thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to do this kind of stuff.

An uglier way is to override your class's **init** method in a mock class like:

```
class MyMockedClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.database = not_a_real_database()
        self.data = not_real_data()
```

and then use this new class in your tests.

For your last question, it depends on your project structure and frameworks you might be using. You should ask [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for advice on your project structure.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! So I can make a new class that inherits the properties of the original one, but replaces those methods in `__init__` that I don't want with whatever value I'd like. Did I get it right?

Btw thanks for the suggestion about codereview, didn't know it existed.

Comment: Yes ! Welcome to OOP :)
be careful as this kind of hack tends to lower the quality of your code. OOP and testing are two very large subjects (with many good books written about).

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. Can you point out some relatively in-depth articles about it: while I understand the basics and the reasoning behind OOP, most examples / guides I find online are too simplified to apply to real world cases.

Comment: I don't have any that come to mind, maybe ask https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Answer (score 1):

You can still call a class method without making an instance of it, but you will have problems if you're trying to call attributes that you have defined in `__init__`.

You might also want to think about making a blank variable data outside of the `__init__` and then call `classinstance.data = classinstance.query_database()` in your main code.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the 1st part, but then again yeah I'd have problems because the method would be checking the attributes defined in `__init__`.

Thanks for the 2nd suggestion btw

Comment: So judging by you're latest edit, I would just make the class instance, let it query the database in initialisation, then simply overwrite ```classinstance.data = mockdata``` afterwards